# Modified code is not correct for the getvalue and setvalue

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4, dom-events

1. My code was working fine but they wanted to change my code....
2. they wanted to attach setValue and getValue added directly to
   footballPanel instead of sports grid,
3. but after adding it the code is not working fine...
4. can you tell me why its not working....
5. providing my modified code below...
6. the UI action here I am performing is there are two radio buttons,
   when I click each radio button two different grids open
7. in one of the grid we add value, when i switch back to another radio
   button the values in another grid disappears but it should not
   disappear...
8. after I modified the code the values disappear, can you tell me why?

**Only part of modified code here**

```
else {
        this.setDisabled(true);
        this.addCls("sports-item-disabled");
        if (sportsGrid.store.getCount() > 0) {
           var footballPanel = sportsGrid.up('panel');
           footballPanel.holdValue = footballPanel.getValue();
           footballPanel.setValue();
           sportsGrid.addCls("sports-item-disabled");
        }
   }
```

**Whole modified code:**

```
sportsContainerHandler: function(radioGroup, newValue, oldValue, options) {
        var sportsCustomParams = options.sportsCustomParams;
        var uiPage = this.up('football-ux-sports-ui-page');
        var SportsDefinition = metamodelsHelper.getSportsDefinition(
            uiPage, sportsCustomParams.SportsHandlerDefinitionId);
        var sportsFieldParam = SportsDefinition.params['sportsMultiFieldName'];
        var sportsGrid = uiPage.queryById(sportsFieldParam.defaultValue).grid;
        if (newValue[radioGroup.name] == 'sportss') {
            this.setDisabled(false);
            this.removeCls("sports-item-disabled");
            if (sportsGrid.holdValue) {
                var footballPanel = sportsGrid.up('panel');
                footballPanel.setValue(sportsGrid.holdValue);
            }
        } else {
            this.setDisabled(true);
            this.addCls("sports-item-disabled");
            **if (sportsGrid.store.getCount() > 0) {
                var footballPanel = sportsGrid.up('panel');
                footballPanel.holdValue = footballPanel.getValue();
                footballPanel.setValue();
                sportsGrid.addCls("sports-item-disabled");
            }**
        }
    },
```

**Working code without modification**

```
sportsContainerHandler: function(radioGroup, newValue, oldValue, options) {
    var sportsCustomParams = options.sportsCustomParams;
    var uiPage = this.up('football-ux-sports-ui-page');
    var SportsDefinition = metamodelsHelper.getSportsDefinition(
        uiPage, sportsCustomParams.SportsHandlerDefinitionId);
    var sportsFieldParam = SportsDefinition.params['sportsMultiFieldName'];
    var sportsGrid = uiPage.queryById(sportsFieldParam.defaultValue).grid;
    if (newValue[radioGroup.name] == 'sportss') {
        this.setDisabled(false);
        this.removeCls("sports-item-disabled");
        if (sportsGrid.holdValue) {
            var footballPanel = sportsGrid.up('panel');
            footballPanel.setValue(sportsGrid.holdValue);
        }
    } else {
        this.setDisabled(true);
        this.addCls("sports-item-disabled");
        if (sportsGrid.store.getCount() > 0) {
            sportsGrid.holdValue = sportsGrid.store.data.items;
            sportsGrid.store.loadData([]);
            sportsGrid.addCls("sports-item-disabled");
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`getValue()` is not a method of [ExtJS Panel class](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel).

The change in your code, from `sportsGrid` ([Ext.grid.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel)) to `footbalPanel` ([Ext.panel.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel)) won't work, because they are from different classes and therefore have different properties and methods.

If you want this code to work, you'll need to implement `getValue()` and `setValue()`. For example, something like:

On FootballPanel class:

```
getValue: function () {
    return this.down('grid').store.data.items;
},

setValue: function (newValue) {
    if (!newValue)
        newValue = new Array();

    this.down('grid').store.loadData(newValue);
},
```

And use your modified code:

```
sportsContainerHandler: function(radioGroup, newValue, oldValue, options) {
    var sportsCustomParams = options.sportsCustomParams;
    var uiPage = this.up('football-ux-sports-ui-page');
    var SportsDefinition = metamodelsHelper.getSportsDefinition(
        uiPage, sportsCustomParams.SportsHandlerDefinitionId);
    var sportsFieldParam = SportsDefinition.params['sportsMultiFieldName'];
    var sportsGrid = uiPage.queryById(sportsFieldParam.defaultValue).grid;
    if (newValue[radioGroup.name] == 'sportss') {
        this.setDisabled(false);
        this.removeCls("sports-item-disabled");
        if (sportsGrid.holdValue) {
            var footballPanel = sportsGrid.up('panel');
            footballPanel.setValue(sportsGrid.holdValue);
        }
    } else {
        this.setDisabled(true);
        this.addCls("sports-item-disabled");
        if (sportsGrid.store.getCount() > 0) {
            var footballPanel = sportsGrid.up('panel');
            footballPanel.holdValue = footballPanel.getValue();
            footballPanel.setValue([]);
            sportsGrid.addCls("sports-item-disabled");
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: thanks for your reply....can you add your code in  the whole code...its confusing

Comment: The `getValue` and `setValue` implementation I proposed should go on the `footballPanel` class. To put it in the right place, I would need more information on how your code is organized.